# What does it mean when a DNS name starts with xn--?

Tags: dns, domain, unicode

I found the following domain in my logs:

```
http://xn--q1a.xn--b1aube0e.xn--c1acygb.xn--p1ai/
```

I have never seen anything like it. Is this a valid domain? If so what is the TLD?

Comment: Why didn't you just try it in a web-browser? Anyway it's a *safe* way to represent domains with unicode characters. This one translates to http://с.новым.годом.рф/

Comment: I did try it in a web browser. I have never seen such a TLD, hence the question.

Comment: This is a special string encoding called [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it's an ascii representation of: .рф

"The domain name рф (romanized as rf [3]) is the Cyrillic country code top-level domain for the Russian Federation, in the Domain Name System of the Internet. In the Domain Name System it has the ASCII DNS name xn--p1ai. The domain accepts only Cyrillic subdomain applications, and is the first Cyrillic implementation of the Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) system."

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.%D1%80%D1%84